# How to set a checkbox to true using WebDriver.io

Tags: javascript, webdriver, webdriver-io

How can I check a checkbox using WebDriver.io?

Simply clicking it does not work..

```
browser.click('input[name="my-checkbox"]');
```

I only found [isSelected](http://webdriver.io/api/state/isSelected.html) but as the name suggests it does not change the checkbox state.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Solved clicking on the label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved clicking on the label that wraps the checkbox:

```
const checkboxesLabels = browser.elements('.mwc-checkbox-custom');
checkboxesLabels.value.forEach((label) => label.click());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the checkbox should work just fine. Here's an example:
http://try.webdriver.io/share/iOPQs7T0kcG1DOzM

If you run that test, you'll see it log out 'false' first, then 'true' after the click.

Maybe the element selector was incorrect, or something was in the way.

Comment: Nice tool ! : )

Comment: link gives a "bad gateway" error currently unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, that service is no longer available, so the link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @KevinLamping unfortunately link is not working, do you mind add snipped here too, best